# Erro acessar página com certificado digital através do WebBrowser Control Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, navegador-de-internet, assinatura-digital

Estou tentando acessar através do Control WebBrowser do Windows Forms .net 4.0 uma página que exige um certificado digital.
O site só é homologado para as versões 8 e 9 do IE.
A versão do IE da máquina é a 11.
Quando acesso direto do navegador preciso colocar no modo de compatibilidade para funcionar.
Quando acesso através do Controle WebBrowser ele dá erro de script falando que não consegue criar o objeto Active X "GeckoActiveXObject não está definido".
Pesquisei e vi que precisaria adicionar uma valor a uma chave de registro(FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION) para executar o controle WebBrowser em modo de compatibilidade coloquei todos os valores possíveis e não obtive resultado positivo.
A única forma que funciona é utilizando um Controle WebBrowser em um projeto WPF com framework 4.5.
Alguém conhece alguma forma de funcionar em windows forms com .net 4.0.
Atenciosamente.